# How to take an array of bytes over a socket

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, client, byte

Good evening.  There is a socket connection.  Messages from the server are 8 bytes.  How do I read them in as an endless stream until there is a connection?  The client portion is written in Java.

Comment: Do you mean there is a client connected to a sever thru TCP socket and the server sends 8 bytes and you want the client reads that bytes in a loop until the server close the connection?

Comment: at the touch of a button on the server, it sends a message to - 8 bytes. the client must receive the same messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from a socket 8 bytes until the server close the socket use something similar to this:

```
void readSocket(Socket socket)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[8];
        int ret;
        while (true)
        {
            int offset=0;
            // keep reading until we got 8 bytes
            while (offset < data.length)
            {
                // when read returns 0 means the socket is closed.
                // if return < 0 there is an error in both cases we must quit.
                if ((ret = socket.getInputStream().read(data, offset, data.length-offset)) <= 0) return;
                offset+=ret;
            }
            // We got 8 bytes, process them
            // ... and loop for next packet
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // there is an error in the socket, quit.
        return;
    }
}
```